# Maven execute plugin just before creating war but after archiving classes

Tags: java, maven, jarsigner, maven-war-plugin, maven-jarsigner-plugin

My main problem is I have to sign all the JARs of WEB-INF\lib folder.

So this is what I have done:-

- Enabled **archiveClasses** option to package classes also into JAR
- Added JAR-Signer Plugin and setting the archive directory to ${project.build.directory}\${project.build.finalName}\WEB-INF\lib

After package finishes, I can check that in target directory all JARs in lib folder are signed but my war file contains unsigned JAR only. Most probably because the jar-signer executed after maven-war-plugin has created the war file.
I tried with setting JAR-Signer to pre-package phase also, but the lib folder is not present by then.

So what I need is to execute Maven JAR-Signer just before maven creates the war file from target directory.

Thanks

Comment: Just an idea to try: put `maven-jarsigner-plugin` below `maven-jar-plugin` and above `maven-war-plugin` in `pom.xml`. The phase should be `package`.

Comment: I ended up creating my own custom soultion to unpack war, sign dependencies and pack it again..

Comment: Hi @kleash, Can please share your solution for signing of Jar files by unpacking and packing war, using maven Jar-Signer. Many thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: hi @arjun99 sorry it's an old post. I no longer have that code with me